# hidding table rows classic asp

Tags: html, regex, vbscript, asp-classic, pagination

I'm using paging on my webpage, so for each letter I press it would display records starting with that character. However my problem is that I need to use # to display everything but characters, so that it will include records that begin with e.g - 1, 323, _, !, etc. How would I use a regular expression to compare values like say -

```
if left(selectedRecord, 1) <> "[^a-z]" then
```

I used to use a store procedure to do this but because checkboxes are problematic when paging I just pull all records and filter like this -

```
response.Write "<tr"
if trim(request.Form("selected_Button")) = "#" then

elseif trim(request.Form("selected_Button")) <> lcase(trim(left(objRS("Movies"), 1))) and len(request.Form("selected_Button")) = 1 then
    response.Write " style=""display:none;"""

end if
response.Write ">"
```

So my question is how would I fix the # as I used in my stored procedure -

```
select * from Movies where movies like '[^a-z]%'
```

Paging Buttons -

```
<center><input id="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="Selected_Button" value="#">
    <% for i = 97 to 122 %>
         <input id="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="Selected_Button" value="<%=CHR(i) %>">&nbsp;
    <% next %></center>
<center></br><input id="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="Selected_Button" value="View All"></center>
```

**EDIT**:

So i found a solution myself but i want to know if i can do this without looping through the alphabet -

```
response.Write "<tr"
if trim(request.Form("selected_Button")) = "#" then
    for i = 97 to 122 
        if lcase(trim(left(objRS("Movies"), 1))) = chr(i) then
            response.Write " style=""display:none;"""
        end if
    next
elseif trim(request.Form("selected_Button")) <> lcase(trim(left(objRS("Movies"), 1))) and len(request.Form("selected_Button")) = 1 then
    response.Write " style=""display:none;"""

end if
response.Write ">"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually ask here is "how to identify the first character is a letter?" and the answer is replace this loop:

```
for i = 97 to 122 
    if lcase(trim(left(objRS("Movies"), 1))) = chr(i) then
        response.Write " style=""display:none;"""
    end if
next
```

With this instead:

```
firstChar = Left(UCase(Trim(objRS("Movies"))), 1)
If firstChar>="A" And firstChar<="Z" Then
    response.Write " style=""display:none;"""
End If
```

Simple comparison will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

My edit will fix this problem -

```
response.Write "<tr"
if trim(request.Form("selected_Button")) = "#" then
    for i = 97 to 122 
        if lcase(trim(left(objRS("Movies"), 1))) = chr(i) then
            response.Write " style=""display:none;"""
        end if
    next
elseif trim(request.Form("selected_Button")) <> lcase(trim(left(objRS("Movies"), 1))) and len(request.Form("selected_Button")) = 1 then
    response.Write " style=""display:none;"""

end if
response.Write ">"
```